# ProcessPoolExecutor gets stuck, ThreadPool Executor does not

Tags: python-3.x

I have an application that lets me select whether to use threads or processes:

```
def _get_future(self, workers):
        if self.config == "threadpool":
            self.logger.debug("using thread pools")
            executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers)
        else:
            self.logger.debug("using process pools")
            executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers)
        return executor
```

Later I execute the code:

```
self.executor = self._get_future()
for component in components:
    self.logger.debug("submitting {} to future ".format(component))
    self.future_components.append(self.executor.submit
                                              (self._send_component, component))

    # Wait for all tasks to finish
while self.future_components:
    self.future_components.pop().result()
```

When I use processes, my Applications gets stuck. The _send_component method is never called. When I use threads all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the imperative approach, this is a use case for a functional approach.

self._send_component is a member function of a class. Separate processes mean no joint memory to share variables.

The solution was to rewrite the code so that _send_component is a static method.